# Equalities with powers of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

For which $z\in\mathbb{C}$ do the following hold:

> 1 $(i^i)^z=i^{iz}$,
>   2 ($i^3)^z=i^{3z}$?

I know that $(i^i)^z=\exp(zi\text{Log}(i)$, but the next steps I don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the complex exponential of a complex number $w^z=e^{z\log w}$ is ambiguous because the logarithm of the complex number $w$ is a multi valued function. If we use the principal value of the log function, than we can find one value of the exponential using the polar form for the basis $w=\rho e^{i\theta}$ and the binomial form for the exponent $z=x+iy$.
$$
w^z= e^{(x+iy)(\log \rho +i\theta)} =e^{(x\log \rho-y\theta)}e^{(x\theta+y\log \rho)}
$$

so, from your question, we have:
$$
i^i=e^{i(i\pi/2)}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$
and
$$
\left(i^i\right)^z=\left(e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)^{(x+iy)}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}x}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}y}
$$

In the same way you can calculate 
$$i^{iz}=e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(ix-y)}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}x}e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}y}
$$
(and you see that it is the same)

and you can do the same for the other exponential.